# Dapper passing DateOnly parameter to HttpGet

Tags: sql-server, dapper

Using Dapper I creating a HttpGet passing a date but getting errors on some date formats.

I have a SQL table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AsOfDate] [date] NOT NULL
    [Sales] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Using Dapper I created a class (MyTable.cs):

```
    public class MyTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? theDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Sales { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a controller [HttpGet] where I want to pass the theDate to the select statement:

```
        [HttpGet("{thedate}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<MyTable>>> GetDataByDate(DateTime? thedate)
        {

            using var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            var myresults = await connection.QueryAsync<MyTable>("select * from MyTable where asofdate = @someDate",
                        new { someDate = thedate });
            return Ok(myresults );
        }
```

This works but if I run any of the below:
2023-04-30T00:00:00
2023-04-30
04-30-2023

If I change
from:

```
public DateTime? theDate { get; set; }
```

to :

```
public DateOnly? theDate { get; set; }
```

I get an error when I run even though SQL table has defined [AsOfDate] [date].

I also get an error when I try to pass 04/30/2023.

Any suggestions as to how to set this up properly? A Web App will be passing a date from the calendar to control to this [httpget]

Comment: Dapper + DateOnly... [not yet](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+DateOnly)

Answer (score 3):

The easier solution is to convert the `DateOnly` value when you use as parameter in the Dapper query:

`new { someDate = thedate.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue) }`

Or you could try to create a custom converter, as suggested in the issue [.NET 6 DateOnly and TimeOnly mapping support #1715 on GitHub](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/1715).

```cs
public class DapperSqlDateOnlyTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DateOnly>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, DateOnly date)
        => parameter.Value = date.ToDateTime(new TimeOnly(0, 0));
    
    public override DateOnly Parse(object value)
        => DateOnly.FromDateTime((DateTime)value);
}
```

and use it as:

```cs
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DateOnlyTypeHandler());
```

Comment: getting ToDateTime could not be found

Comment: It's my fault, [`ToDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.todatetime?view=net-7.0#system-dateonly-todatetime(system-timeonly) is a method of `DateOnly` struct, but you have a trouble converting data from table to output DTO and not setting parameters since the value is already a DateTime. Try to set the converter if it works.

Comment: I will handle it from web app making sure its in the format its looking for. Trying not to over complicate it.